# Why is the variable argument of this required function returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My HTML templates were getting too long so I decided to put them in a separate file (I'm using Babel.js):

**template.js:**

```
exports.contents = function(data) {
  return `<html>
  <head>
    <title>Book name</title>
  </head>
    <body>
    <h2>${data}</h2>
  </body>
</html>`
}
```

To use in here:

**app.js:**

```
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  // I'm converting Markdown to HTML. In this case the
  // the file just has the text: This is some data
  let result = convertToHTML(data)
  fs.writeFile("untitled.html", result, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(result)
      console.log(template.contents(result))
    }
  })
})
```

`console.log(result)` outputs the right result:

```
<p>This is some data</p>
```

But `console.log(template.contents(result))` outputs this instead:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Book name</title>
  </head>
    <body>
    <h2>undefined</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

What's happening here?

**EDIT:**

Here's the convertToHTML function:

```
function convertToHTML(markdownSource) {
  let data = markdownSource.split(/\n\n|^>(?!.)/gm)
    , orig = data.slice()
    , conversions = [ convertHeadings, convertQuotes, convertDashes, 
                      convertStyling, convertParagraphs ]
  // use an original copy so the match comparison is always clean 
  for (let i = 0, l = orig.length; i < l; ++i) {
    for (let conversion of conversions) {
      let result = conversion(data[i], orig[i], orig[i - 1])

      if (result !== undefined) {
        data[i] = result
      }
    }
  }
  return data.join('\n\n')
}
```

Comment: possibly you wrong call `template.contents(result)` and possibly it should be like `template.contents({data:result})`

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you add the `convertToHTML` function?

Comment: [worksforme](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true&code=var%20contents%20%3D%20function(data)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%60%3Chtml%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Chead%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EBook%20name%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fhead%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbody%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch2%3E%24%7Bdata%7D%3C%2Fh2%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fbody%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E%60%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Avar%20result%20%3D%20%22%3Cp%3EThis%20is%20some%20data%3C%2Fp%3E%22%0D%0Aconsole.log(contents(result))). Are you using native `node --harmony` or what environment?

Comment: @FelixKling so strange, seems like template string not see `data` in parameters, possibly if save it in local variable it will work?

Comment: @Grundy It sees that clearly. Check Bergi's babel sample.

Comment: @Seth I added the `convertToHTML` function

Comment: @Bergi I'm using babel.js.

Comment: @thefourtheye i try it, it working, but i mean in case OP, on his environment

Comment: @Grundy: `data` is already local because it is a parameter.

Comment: @alexchenco: Can you post the compiled es5 files maybe? That'll let us track the mistake down.

Comment: In es5 https://gist.github.com/sethkrasnianski/cf92fcb10a8dc271274b. Compiled with babel.js

Comment: @Bergi Here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0684f0c591c2c925e4e2. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[That](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0684f0c591c2c925e4e2#file-gistfile1-js-L132)'s a simple one:

> ```
> console.log(result);
> console.log(template.contents());
> ```

Maybe you want to pass something to your function? :-)

Comment: I hope this is not a babel bug, but on oversight by the OP…

Comment: in @Seth [variant](https://gist.github.com/sethkrasnianski/cf92fcb10a8dc271274b) correct `console.log(template.contents(result));` so possibly simple typo

Comment: But I think there's no typo?

Comment: Hm, if you can reproduce to output this argument-less code from the ES6 you posted in your question, you really will need to report that as a babel bug. Make sure to get the latest version of everything, and then try to reduce your code to become a minimal example.

Comment: @Bergi Dang! I accidentally pressed undo in my text editor and I reverted to `console.log(template.contents())` but I didn't realize that because my SO question still had the right version: `console.log(template.contents(result))`. Anyway, thanks a lot!